# Change the Label color inside the Pie chart

Tags: tableau-api

1. Change the Label color inside the Pie chart's darker region to white
2. Keep the label i.e present outside the pie chart in the same font color(black)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIovF.png)

Answer (score 3):

You can't manipulate the font colour using single filed, instead you need to manipulate individually to get conditional color formatting.

you are changing the color component so use that to manipulate the colour of font.

For example if my date is changing the colour component then use the date to change the colour of font. Follow below steps:

1. Create a calculated field `Value1`

`if date=2011  //For demo purpose I assume date is used to maipulate the color of bars
then sales
end`

2. Create a calculated field `Value2`

   `if date=2012  //For demo purpose I assume date is used to maipulate the color of bars
   then sales
   end`

Now place calculated fields both `value1` and `value2` on label marks

Then go to **edit text** part of the edit lable their select `value1` apply color `white` and select `value2` and apply color `grey`

[image]

Comment: @Ashwin if solution works for you please accept it as answer and close the thread

Comment: Thank you very much, I was also looking how could one change the color of a label that is present outside a Pie chart in Tableau?

Comment: @Ashwin follow the same logic as bar chart

Comment: Okay, but I am looking to change only the color of LABELS that are present outside the pie chart. So how would you differentiate between labels that are present inside the pie chart to the ones present outside?

Comment: Edit your question with Pie chart image and explain the problem, I am unable to understand what is the exact issue

Comment: @Ashwin have you treid the logic in answer, this should work for your edited question, Also when you edit a question you shouldn't delete the old one instead append the new question to old one